# Change Azure Website Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I had a free trial with windows azure, I was out of the country and it ran out.

I have now upgraded to a pay-as-you-go account. All good.

However, my previous websites still run off my old subscription, is there any way to reactivate these websites using my new pay-as-you-go subscription?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you upgraded the existing free account versus opened a new pay-as-you-go account, this should have been a seamless transition.

You can [contact support](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) - use the Billing Questions option and then select Transfer Subscription, and they should be able to help you.

Alternatively, of course, you could redeploy your assets to the new subscription.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Yes it should have been seamless but I was away and missed upgrading it and the subscription ended so I couldn't upgrade it unfortunately. I contacted support and they said a subscription for websites cannot be changed so I had to redeploy. Of course this is so easy in Azure so it didn't really make much difference to me. Still kinda sad you cant change subscriptions though.

Comment: Just got off the line with Microsoft Support. It is not possible to move a single Azure website from one *subscription* to another.  It seems that they can only be moved by *account*, and not subscriptions.  All Azure websites and other services, including VMs, must be moved together, **AND** the new account cannot have any Azure websites in any subscriptions.  I want to move one website from one subscription to another in the **same** account and it was not possible to do so.

Comment: so if I created a VM (and installed a bunch of stuff on it) in the free trial subscription, does "redeploy" mean that I have to create a new VM and reinstall everything?

Comment: @ekkis, no. if you convert before the trial expires it will carry over seamlessly

Comment: @paqogomez, unfortunately, I couldn't get the new account set up before the old account expired, so now I have to do it the hard way, I guess...

Comment: @ekkis Ya, but its not that hard. Call MS Support, they'll walk you through it for free.  They even had a telephone option specifically for this when I called.

Comment: Can't move resources from a disabled subscription because the sub is disabled and therefore read-only. Wonderful.

Answer (score 6):

I created a "Billing" ticket with microsoft.  There is a type of ticket as you go through their wizard specifically for this.  They were able to upgrade my "Free Trial" to the pay as you go AFTER i had let the free trial expire.  The downside was that all my virtual machines were deleted.  It did however give me access to my websites and storage without any problem.  I was able to recreate all the VM's using the storage vhd's.

Comment: ouch.  so glad I went through all the trouble of installing and configuring stuff on my VM

Comment: @ekkis, you just have to create the new vm's based on the image in your storage. All your settings will be there.

Answer (score 5):

My experience on this is that I just redeploy to a new website I created under new subscription. I didn't find a way to move them over to new subscription.

You can move SQL Azure to new subscription, but not website. To move SQL Azure to new subscription, you will need to use old Azure portal management. Follow this step:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/03/07/moving-sql-azure-servers-between-subscriptions.aspx
Note that you are moving the server where the database lives. So, if you have more than one DB in the same server, everything will be moved.

Comment: The documentation in the link is no longer applicable.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation in the link stack247 posted is now outdated.  To change the target subscription for a database, you have to change the target subscription of the server for the database.  There are several ways to navigate to the server, but here is just one example:

1. Click on the **database** tab
2. Click on the **name of the database** you want to change
3. In the **dashboard** view, click on the link to the server in the **quick glance** section.  This is on the **bottom right** corner of the view.
4. In the **dashboard** view, click on the **Change Subscription** link in the **quick glance** section.  This is on the **right side** of the view.
5. Change the **Target Subscription**, and click the **check** button.

As far as changing the subscription for a website or cloud service, I would do what is recommended above; and republish the website or cloud service.  When you publish, change the settings to target a different subscription by clicking on the previous button.

---------Update----------

If you have a bunch of assets that need to be moved to another account, create a ticket with the Azure helpdesk.  You will have to do the above and switch out the accounts for the databases/servers, but Microsoft is able to run a script on their end that moves everything.  Depending on the size of your assets, it may take a little longer.  Fortunately for me, it was only a day to move everything.  I would recommend doing this instead of publishing everything a second time.

https://manage.windowsazure.com/?getsupport=true

Answer (score 4):

You can move Azure SQL DB from one subscription to another on https://manage.windowsazure.com

Both subscriptions should in the same Default Directory. If they are in different directories then select:

- *Subscriptions*
- *Manage subscriptions/directory*
- Select subscription and click *"Edit"* at the bottom.
- Choose directory where other subscription and click "Next".

When both subscriptions in the same directory.

- Choose *"SQL Databases"*
- Select proper server
- and in Quick Glance you should see *"Change subscription"*

Answer (score 3):

All the solutions mentioned above are now outdated. 
In the https://portal.azure.com/,

1. For SQL Servers, go in the "SQL Servers" menu, select the server to change. In the Overview, click on the Edit button, located right to the name of the subscription.
2. For WebApps, go to the "App Service plans" menu, select your plan, click on the Resource Group and in the Overview, click on the Edit button, located right to the name of the subscription.