# Windows Azure free trial expired - change service to new subscription?

Tags: azure, subscription

My free trial has expired and I created new subscription. How to change old subscripted mobile service to new?

I can't log into mobile service etc. from management panel...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Azure Website Subscription](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876984/change-azure-website-subscription)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if they can do this for expired trial subscriptions, as deployments may well have been removed, but Windows Azure support can move deployments between [active] subscriptions, so worth pinging them?