# Transfer website from free subscription to pay as you go

Tags: azure

I had a web app in Azure that was created with free subscription. Now the free subscription has expired and the site is not functional. So I have changed my subscription to pay as you go. But I think I'm not able to figure out where my previous application is now.

I looked at some of the links already on this topic on Stackoverflow and they asks to delete the previous service and redeploy it.

**EDIT:** I know it is a duplicate question and I have already gone through [Change Azure Website Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876984/change-azure-website-subscription) link

**What is creating the trouble:** During this process I'm not seeing my previous service at all in the management portal so how should I delete it? If I drop the idea of deleting the service and directly start creating a new service, then I'm not able to use the same url which I had previously as it is flagged as being already in use.

Comment: @paqogomez yes I have already gone through this link but the link asks me to delete and redeploy the application, but how should I delete it, i'm not seeing it in the management portal

Comment: I've gone through this process (my answer is on that page) and there was nothing of delete and redeploy.  You need to upgrade your free account rather than create a new one.

Comment: yes I did that.. now how can I use the same url as my previous service... it is already in use...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself... I wanted to either get back my previous web app or delete the previous one so that a new web app can be created with the same url.

I switched to the new Azure Portal which clearly showed my old and deactivated apps which were not visible in the previous portal. In the **Browse all** section of the preview portal it showed my previous applications. So there I simply deleted the app and created a new one with the same url... :) :) :)

You can visit it at [Azure Preview Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#).